# in-process Replicated cache with Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I would like to know if it is a common approach to start instances of a java application with an in-process replicated cache, assuming the volume of data is relatively Low, and the Writes are very low (close to static data).

By in-process replicated cache I mean the java application run as server mode, and there is no dedicated Ignite cluster.

basically If I run 3 instances of my application, then I get 3 server nodes that will automatically replicate data across my 3 applications. If I stop all instances, then there is no nodes anymore (data is lost if no persistence enabled). so the "cluster" is dedicated to that app, and only exist while there are running instances of my application.

Read will be extremely fast, all being local in memory. Number of Writes being low there will be a low network impact. That in-process ignite cluster will only host the cache of this application, so there is no overhead linked to other cache that the app would not control.

Server nodes might stress CPU of my java application, but if Writes are Low and all reads are local, I don't think there will be a lot of overhead being a server nodes, so I think it is acceptable but I want to check with you. If my services are scaling up and down horizontally very frequently then I guess it will impact all (some of) my instances as there will be some communication to replicate to the new instances.

an alternative would be to create a dedicated Ignite cluster and use a client node + near-cache, but it adds some complexity.